# Control the tie-breaking choice for loading chunks in the scheduler?

Tags: dask

I have some large files in a local binary format, which contains many 3D (or 4D) arrays as a series of 2D chunks.  The order of the chunks in the files is random (could have chunk 17 of variable A, followed by chunk 6 of variable B, etc.).  I don't have control over the file generation, I'm just using the results.  Fortunately the files contain a table of contents, so I know where all the chunks are without having to read the entire file.

I have a simple interface to lazily load this data into dask, and re-construct the chunks as `Array` objects.  This works fine - I can slice and dice the array, do calculations on them, and when I finally `compute()` the final result the chunks get loaded from file appropriately.

However, the order that the chunks are loaded is not optimal for these files.  If I understand correctly, for tasks where there is no difference of cost (in terms of # of dependencies?), the local threaded scheduler will use the task keynames as a tie-breaker. This seems to cause the chunks to be loaded in their logical order within the Array.  Unfortunately my files do not follow the logical order, so this results in many seeks through the data (e.g. seek halfway through the file to get chunk `(0,0,0)` of variable A, then go back near the beginning to get chunk `(0,0,1)` of variable A, etc.).  What I would like to do is somehow control the order that these chunks get read, so they follow the order in the file.

I found a kludge that works for simple cases, by creating a callback function on the `start_state`.  It scans through the tasks in the `'ready'` state, looking for any references to these data chunks, then re-orders those tasks based on the order of the data on disk.  Using this kludge, I was able to speed up my processing by a factor of **3**.  I'm guessing the OS is doing some kind of read-ahead when the file is being read sequentially, and the chunks are small enough that several get picked up in a single disk read.  This kludge is sufficient for my current usage, however, it's ugly and brittle.  It will probably work against dask's optimization algorithm for complex calculations.  Is there a better way in dask to control which tasks win in a tie-breaker, in particular for loading chunks from disk?  I.e., is there a way to tell dask, *"all things being equal, here's the relative order I'd like you to process this group of chunks?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assessment is correct.  As of 2018-06-16 there is not currently any way to add in a final tie breaker.  In the distributed scheduler (which works fine on a single machine) you can provide explicit priorities with the `priority=` keyword, but these take precedence over all other considerations.